# Live video stream with webcam in web and predict result from a keras model and show live stream data in a dashboard

Tags: python, web, keras, computer-vision

I make a kares model thats predict emotion from live video feed using webcam. I want to make publish this model in web also show the result in a dashboard. I am trying it with Django but real time data has not sync. Can anyone help me give a proper guideline for deploy the model and publish this in web. I am absolutely beginner.

Answer (score 0):

Try this and add you ML code, for camera use cv2 camera frame in the place of screenshot frame

[Code for real time streaming with Flask](https://github.com/mdrehan4all/py_stream_screen_over_network/blob/master/web.py)